# При нажатии на картинку выезжает блок css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Верстаю макет из `psd`
На первой картинке простое состояние блока а на второй `hover`.
Как при наведении мыши сделать выезжающий оранжевый блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Недавно был такой же вопрос, но его невозможно отыскать, так как там тоже присутствовала картинка в вопросе. Отличия того вопроса от этого: там по клику "выезжал" зеленый блок.

Comment: а как просто создать такой блок

Answer (score 2):

Если именно hover, а не клик - можно (нужно) без JS. 

Главная использованная фишка: `.класс1:hover .класс2 {...}` — при наведении на класс1, отыскать где-то внутри него класс2 и что-то с ним сделать.

( [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/x9bk5u6q/) )

```css
.block { /* Внешний блок */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #123;
  margin: 10px;
}

.icon-block { /* блок с картинкой и скрытым описанием */
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0; /* чтобы не было пробела под картинкой */
}

.icon-block * {
  line-height: normal;
}

.name { /* название картинки */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.hidden { /* Скрытое описание */
  width: 100%;
  height: 0; /* за счет этого */
  overflow: hidden; /* и этого */
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* прилипнет внизу */
  background-color: #f36700;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* не будет сюрпризов от padding */
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.block:hover .hidden {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block:hover .name {
  color: #f36700;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="icon-block">
    <img class="icon" src="https://gyazo.com/a9219ec9f23cf9420048220a58d288cf.png">
    <div class="hidden">Урон: 50;<br>Здоровье: 150;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Cheburashikus Majoris</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="icon-block">
    <img class="icon" src="https://gyazo.com/92a8f48263dacbbd91628c4755ca9b0d.png">
    <div class="hidden">Урон: 100;<br>Здоровье: 100;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Mimimi</div>
</div>
```